# ProgressIndicator spinning whole time

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, progress-indicator

I'm using a ProgressIndicator and I want it to spin the whole time. It also would be great, if the %-Label will be invisible.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please watch out I think there are other threads with nearly the same question.

But anyway just do this in your initialize():

```
  loading.setProgress(-1);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Might be better to use ProgressIndicator.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS for readability...